# Output redirect complexities

Tags: io-redirection, ksh

I'm trying to have a script exit with an error in the event it can't reach an X server:

```
xset -q &> /dev/null || { echo "The Display Server is BROKEN.  Aborting."; exit 1; }
```

However, I'm getting the output of `xset -q` spat out to the console.  I'm not quite sure why.  My understanding of `&>` was that it redirected all output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to redirect the STDOUT and STDERR to /dev/null for `xset -q`, you should do:

```
xset -q > /dev/null 2>&1 || { echo "The Display Server is BROKEN.  Aborting."; exit 1; }
```

The redirection of using `&>` only works within `bash` or `zsh`. Therefore you should use `2>&1` to let redirection work in all Bourne-like shells.

Comment: Thanks; you clued me in to the fix.  &> seems to be a bash-ism and my fellow DBA had the interpreter set to ksh.  If you could tweak you answer to reflect &> being a bash-ism and that 2>&1 works more portably, I'll set it as the answer.